# How to correctly center my lines of math?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, formatting

I don't have a lot of experience with LaTeX, so when I want to have lines of math centered, I just use `\begin{center}`. Problem is, my output comes out looking really weird, as in the image.[image]

Here's my exact code from this document:

```
 Finally: 
    \begin{center}
        $\dot m = \rho * V * A
        \newline
        0.00347747 \frac{kg}{s} = 0.72 \frac{kg}{m^3} * 2\frac {m}{s} * \frac{\pi*d^2}{4}
        \newline 
        0.00347747 \frac{kg}{s} = 1.129 \frac{kg}{m^2*s}*d^2
        \newline 
        d = \sqrt{0.00308 m^2}
        \newline 
        d = 0.0555 m = 5.55 cm$
    \end{center}
```

So how can I make these lines of math all line up better, so that the centers of the lines are centered?
Any other advice on how I can improve my formatting or anything would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: You should read a proper intruduction to latex and math in latex. Additionally, there are rules as to how one typesets units, see the `siunitx` package. Here I would not center, but place the first `=` above each other using the `align*` env.

Comment: Welcome Cedric a place to start might be https://latex-tutorial.com/tutorials/amsmath/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a rewrite using `siunitx`

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,siunitx}
\sisetup{
  per-mode=fraction,
  group-digits = integer,
}
\begin{document}
 \begin{align*}
   \dot m &= \rho \cdot V \cdot A
   \\
   \SI{0.00347747}{\kg\per\second}
          &=
            \SI{0.72}{\kg\per\meter\cubed}
            \cdot \SI{2}{\meter\per\second}
            \cdot \frac{\pi\cdot d^2}{4}
   \\ 
   \SI{0.00347747}{\kg\per\second}
          &=
            \SI{1.129}{\kg\per\meter\squared\per\second}\cdot d^2
   \\
   d &= \sqrt{\SI{0.00308}{\meter\squared}}
   \\
   d &= \SI{0.0555}{\meter} = \SI{5.55}{\cm}
 \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

If you want everything centered, use `gather*` instead og `align*` and remove all the `&`'s

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Definitely going to use the units from now on, that's way better. And thank you for mentioning the different ways to center. What does the "&" tell LaTeX to do when it's included?

Comment: @Cedric as I mentioned in my initial comment, please read a proper introduction to latex (say away from most youtube videos as many are bad). You might want to visit https://www.learnlatex.org/. In `align` the symbol `&` marks alignments (aka what you want above each other) (usually there is only one, if using more markers in a row `&` also marks space between alignmetns)

Comment: The current `siunitx` uses `\qty` instead of `\SI`. It could conflict with `physics`, but I can't recommend loading it. The first formula should be `\dot{m}&=\rho VA` with braces and no `\cdot`.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for the align environment

\begin{document}
Finally:
\begin{align*}
\dot{m} &= \rho \cdot V \cdot A \\
&= 0.00347747 \, \frac{\text{kg}}{\text{s}} = 0.72 \, \frac{\text{kg}}.   {\text{m}^3} \cdot 2 \, \frac{\text{m}}{\text{s}} \cdot \frac{\pi d^2}{4} \\
&= 0.00347747 \, \frac{\text{kg}}{\text{s}} = 1.129 \, \frac{\text{kg}}{\text{m}^2 \cdot \text{s}} \cdot d^2 \\
d &= \sqrt{0.00308 \, \text{m}^2} \\
&= 0.0555 \, \text{m} = 5.55 \, \text{cm}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Is this wha you would like?

Comment: Try adding `\itshape` outside of `align*` to see why one should never use `\text` here. Use `siunitx`

Comment: Thanks, I was just giving a place to start.

Comment: @daleif And there is no need for \cdot in `\rhoVA` would be just fine in math and preferred.  I would leave them though in the units explaining how mass flow rate `kg/s` comes about, but maybe use slashes to show how they cancel.